# What would be the complexity of this Sorting Algorithm? What are the demerits of using the same?

Tags: sorting, big-o, binary-search-tree

The sorting algorithm can be described as follows:

**1. Create Binary Search Tree from the Array data.**

(For multiple occurences, increment occurence variable of the current Node)

**2. Traverse BST in inorder fashion.**

(Inorder traversal will return Sorted order of elements in array).

**3. At each node in inorder traversal, overwrite the array element at current index(index beginning at 0) with current node value.**

Here's a Java implementation for the same:

**Structure of Node Class**

```
class Node {
    Node left;
    int data;
    int occurence;
    Node right;
}
```

**inorder function**
(returning type is int just for obtaining correct indices at every call, they serve no other purpose)

```
public int inorder(Node root,int[] arr,int index) {
    if(root == null) return index;
    index = inorder(root.left,arr,index);
    for(int i = 0; i < root.getOccurence(); i++)
        arr[index++] = root.getData();
    index = inorder(root.right,arr,index);
    return index;
}
```

**main()**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[]{100,100,1,1,1,7,98,47,13,56};
    BinarySearchTree bst = new BinarySearchTree(new Node(arr[0]));
    for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
        bst.insert(bst.getRoot(),arr[i]);
    int dummy = bst.inorder(bst.getRoot(),arr,0);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

The space complexity is terrible, I know, but it should not be such a big issue unless the sort is used for an extremely HUGE dataset. However, as I see it, isn't Time Complexity O(n)? (Insertions and Retrieval from BST is O(log n), and each element is touched once, making it O(n)). Correct me if I am wrong as I haven't yet studied Big-O well.

Comment: If you goal is to sort an array in O(N*log(N)) time, you can already use a quicksort or mergesort with better space usage and you map from array -> array rather than array -> tree.

Comment: @DougCoburn Actually the goal was to implement an O(n) algorithm to sort an Array of n elements with each element in the range [1, n^2].

Comment: I'm fairly certain that there is no O(n) sorting algorithm. under those constraints.

Comment: @DougCoburn Check out the answer by User rcgldr below. I am currently reading a GeeksForGeeks post about the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the *amortized* (average) complexity of an insertion is `O(log n)`, then `N` inserts (construction of the tree) will give `O(log(1) + log(2) + ... + log(N-1) + log(N)` = `O(log(N!))` = `O(NlogN)` (*Stirling's theorem*). To read back the sorted array, perform an *in-order depth-first traversal*, which visits each node once, and is hence `O(N)`. Combining the two you get `O(NlogN)`.

However this requires that the tree is always *balanced*! This will not be the case in general for the most basic binary tree, as insertions do not check the relative depths of each child tree. There are many variants which are self-balancing - the two most famous being *Red-Black trees* and *AVL trees*. However the implementation of balancing is quite complicated and often leads to a higher constant factor in real-life performance.

Comment: Great Explanation! Thanks for such a quick reply. How can I Accept this Answer as a solution to the question?

Comment: Got it! +1 for a concise explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> the goal was to implement an O(n) algorithm to sort an Array of n elements with each element in the range [1, n^2]

In that case Radix sort (counting variation) would be O(n), taking a fixed number of passes (logb(n^2)), where b is the "base" used for the field, and b a function of n, such as b == n, where it would take two passes, or b == sqrt(n), where it would take four passes, or if n is small enough, b == n^2 in where it would take one pass and counting sort could be used. b could be rounded up to the next power of 2 in order to replace division and modulo with binary shift and binary and. Radix sort needs O(n) extra space, but so do the links for a binary tree.

Comment: +1 Good solution. I still can't wrap my head around how it will be an O(n) algorithm. Will look into it.

Comment: Interesting solution. If the values are constrained to be [1, n^2] you can do a radix sort over n buckets in two (constant) passes which makes the final solution O(n).  Sounds like an interview or homework question.

Comment: @SaketKulkarni - I updated my answer to note that as Doug Coburn commented, b is function of n such as b == n (two passes) or b = sqrt(n) (four passes).

Comment: @DougCoburn You got me ;) Algorithms Assignment.